# How to understand node version dependencies issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I am working on a nodejs project. I get below error when launch the application.

```
Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
extensionHostProcess.js:293
Expected directory: node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module '/Users/dev/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node
```

From the description it means there are unmatched native dependencies version related to `firebase`. I tried `npm rebuild` which doesn't seem to work. I am using node version:

```
node: v8.9.4
npm: 6.2.0
```

How can I fix the dependencies issue? Should I try with particular node version or should I rebuilt some native libraries?